# Does Hashing.crc32 generate a unique string if the hashString is a nanotime?

Tags: java, algorithm, uniqueidentifier, unique-key, url-shortener

I'm developing an url shortener and I have to generate in java a unique string like this "**3d0d1fb8**", to have a short url like this: **shrt.it/3d0d1fb8**

I'm using this code:

```
String nanotime = String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());    
String uniqueId = Hashing.crc32().hashString(nanotime, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
```

Is this "**uniqueId**" a really unique string?

Comment: No, it's not unique.

Comment: Your output dimension is fixed sized, therefore a clear no. There are infinitely many inputs that result in the output 3d0d1fb8.

Comment: `nanotime` is a 64-bit integer. crc32 is 32 bits. You can't put 2^64 things into a bag that's designed to hold 2^32 things.

Comment: You might consider using [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) instead of hexadecimal to encode your string. That's what YouTube uses for their video ids.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, any 32-bit hash will get a duplicate after about 60K values. Any two strings can have the same hash.

If you want to see how quickly random 32-bit values repeat, you can run this this produces thousands of results in seconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int range = 1 << 30;
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(range);
    while (true) {
        int value = rand.nextInt();
        if (value >= 0 && value < range)
            if (bs.get(value))
                System.out.println("Duplicate " + value);
            else
                bs.set(value);
    }
}
```

A simpler way to get a unique id is to use a timestamp like `System.currentTimeMillis()` converted into base 36, though you can only ensure it is unique for a single JVM.

e.g.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

// unique for a JVM, and ok on restart provided less than 1000 ids/sec
public enum UniqueTimestamp {
    INSTANCE;
    final AtomicLong time = new AtomicLong();

    public long uniqueTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long value = time.get();
        long next = Math.max(now, value) + 1;
        if (time.compareAndSet(value, next))
            return next;
        return time.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public String uniqueId() {
        return Long.toString(uniqueTime(), Character.MAX_RADIX /*36*/);
    }
}
```

where

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        System.out.println(UniqueTimestamp.INSTANCE.uniqueId());
```

prints

```
jae4gmp2
jae4gmp3
jae4gmp4
jae4gmp5
jae4gmp6
```

> What do you do if you have multiple JVMs?

You can add a unique character(s) to the start of each id assigned to the JVM. e.g. one adds `a`, another add `b` etc.

Comment: You can replace 36 with `Character.MAX_RADIX`.

Comment: Further, this neat trick has long been used, e.g., see [ULID](https://github.com/alizain/ulid).

Comment: @VolkanYazıcı I assume the OP wants an id shorter than 128 -bits.

Comment: Why not simply take the first n bits of a SHA256 of a `UUID.randomUUID()`? It's even a one-liner, if one likes those: `byte[] randomBytes = Arrays.copyOf(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes()), numberOfbytesIWant);`

Comment: @D.Kovács like i said at the start, random numbers repeat very quickly for smaller numbers of bits no matter what hash you use.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Any n bits of SHA-256 won't repeat any faster than a timestamp based solution for any given length, and at least it's definitely cryptographically secure + on most systems you will get hardware support for it. And you don't have the limitation of single JVM.

Comment: @D.Kovács a counter repeats every 2^n values, a random value repeats far faster due to the birthday problem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @Peter Lawrey indeed you are right, the hash-based solution needs to be twice as long to provide the uniqueness guarantee, my bad. Still, having 64 bits and having the guarantees of SHA (and across JVMs) is better for me, then having the output limited to 32bits and base it on timestamps. But that's me, and it wasn't the question in the OP. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @D.Kovács for the 128-bit UUID this isn't such a problem (though not all 128 bits are random by design), but shorter hashes can be surprisingly easy to get duplicates. Bit coin and Ethereum used 160 and 256 bit hashes to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yeah, IIRC Java random UUID will have 122 random bits acquired from a `SecureRandom`, that part is still affected by the birthday-paradox though, just still leaving 2**61 possibilities before hitting the paradox.